# Is leaving old Li-ion battery in permanently plugged in laptop dangerous?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a Dell Vostro 3350. Since about 2 months ago it displays on boot
*Your battery has experienced permanent failure and needs to be replaced. Press F1 to continue or F2 to run setup utility*
. The reported capacity dropped to 3Wh from original 80Wh. The battery is old so this is definitely a failure.

I only use the laptop at home, plugged in and don't need the battery, but would like to leave it in so dust won't enter the laptop. I couldn't find a 'dummy battery' to keep the slot closed. Is leaving old Li-ion battery in permanently plugged in laptop dangerous?

Comment: There's no way to definitively answer unless you know the specific reason the battery management PCB reports the battery as bad. For example, if it's due to pressure in one of the 18650 cells, you're relying on the battery management PCB to never fail, and if it stays plugged in and isn't picked up regularly, you'll have no idea if the battery begins to bulge until it's too late. Simply put, replace the battery and take the old one to a place that accepts old batteries for disposal _(Home Depot, etc.)_, as it's not worth the fire risk over ~$40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one here will give you a simple and  guaranteed answer, but it SHOULD be fine (and indeed arguably preferable to running without a battery) if you bear a few thing in mind -

1. Lithium based batterys/chargers have protections against overcharging. Provided these protections are working everything should be fine.
2. If the battery shows signs if swelling, disconnect and dispose if it.  This is often a precursor to a dangerous event.
3. Different lithium based technologies have different degrees of risk. LFP are safer then most older techs.
4. If the battery gets hot that is a warning it is likely unsafe.

It might be wise to leave the computer off when it is unattended.

(The arguments around leaving the battery in  is so it can act as a buffer/power filter and teduce risk of corruption/instability/data loss - from a safety POV its likely safer to remove it.

You may (or may not) be able to mske/get a 3d print dummy battery - or even open the pack (but be careful) and remove the batteries from the pack)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wish to keep the machine running, I found it best to replace the battery (Dr Battery for a FRU specific battery via Amazon) and then run it at the generally accepted level of 80% (or what the manufacturer suggests) charge level to permit always plugged in.

I had the same issue that the existing battery failed, so replacement seemed to be in order.

This worked fine for me, the computer remains running, and no bad outcomes.It is better (in my view) than leaving a failed battery in the machine and plugged in.

Your computer needs to support Battery Threshold Management to run at the 80% level.

I recommend this as a reasonable inexpensive and effective solution.

[Dr Battery replacements](https://drpowerglobal.com/)

There are others but this is the source I use.

Comment: for maximum longevity in an always-plugged-in scenario holding a charge of about 50℅ is preferable to 80%

Comment: I have not seen that. Lenovo says 80%. But I do refine the post

Comment: Per https://support.lenovo.com/sg/en/solutions/ht069687-easy-ways-to-extend-your-battery-life-ideapadlenovothinkpad-laptops "  it is strongly recommended to select Optimize for Battery Lifespan mode or Conservation Mode and keep the AC adapter connected all the time. This mode will enable the battery to be fully charged to 80% or 60% of its design capacity - ie Lenovo recommend 80% for when battery will be used, 60% in always plugged in mode.  I believe the idea of about 50% is that it balances the charge between cathide and anode.

Comment: Lenovo Vantage sets it for 80% . After 4 years no issues

Comment: 80% is certainly a good solution for all-round use (provided you can live with the reduced runtime from 100%) and is generally considered the sweet spot trading battery storage for longevity.  OTOH, new devices ship with a ~60% initial charge to minimize stress while sitting on the shelf (and allowing for gradual discharge).

Comment: @davidgo For optimum battery life, a charging threshold stop of 75% and starting charging at 65% is recommended.  I use 80% myself for practicality and fully charge on occasions when I need max runtime. Lots of information on this at Battery University. https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-808-how-to-prolong-lithium-based-batteries

Comment: @paradroid I can't see where that document makes that statement - the best I can see on that page to support your statement is a reference to describing the best result for "figure 6", where the 75-65 charge is the lowest one.  The document also states "Experiment: Chalmers University of Technology, Sweden, reports that using a reduced charge level of 50% SOC increases the lifetime expectancy of the vehicle Li-ion battery by 44–130%."  https://cleantechnica.com/2021/08/03/lithium-ion-battery-care-guide-summary-of-battery-best-practices/ also supports the 50% claim.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/caring-for-your-surface-battery-9ccdfa7b-d074-f629-425c-1c090ac66bed also says some counter-intuitive things suggesting Surface batteries ideally be kept below 50% for Lithium Ion batteries - however https://www.guidingtech.com/66018/keep-laptop-plugged-in/ says "The study concluded that the optimal charge voltage for Lithium batteries is 3.92v/cell which is roughly equivalent to 60% of battery charge." - so pick your poison!

Comment: @davidgo [This link highlights in Chrome](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-808-how-to-prolong-lithium-based-batteries#:~:text=The%20smallest%20capacity%20loss%20is%20attained%20by%20charging%20Li%2Dion%20to%2075%20percent%20and%20discharging%20to%2065%20percent.%20This%2C%20however%2C%20does%20not%20fully%20utilize%20the%20battery.), or look read the second paragraph after the second graph on the page.

Comment: @davidgo I think the 50% figure could be about battery storage, which Battery University recommends elsewhere on the site. I've been linking to this site on superuser.com for at least a decade and it seems pretty authoritative.

Comment: @paranoid we are largely in agreement and seeing the same things then - I do agree batteryU is an authorative source.   My comment was just that the 75-65% tou refer to refers to charge/discharge and was the smallest range tested, and says nothing about the ideal charge for shallowed discharges, nor does it consider 55-45% or similar.